# Cauchy's Theorem for some region A\{z,w...}

Tags: complex-analysis

Does Cauchy's Theorem hold when we integrate $f$ over a region $A$ such that $f$ is continuous on all the points of $A$ but not analytic (holomorphic) on a finite number of points $z,w...$ contained in $A$?

I.e. $f$ doesn't have to be analytic on all $A$, but continuous on all of it and analytic on all of it except a finite number of points. Correct?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and holomorphic on $A\setminus D$, where $D$ is a discrete subset of $A$ (e.g. finite), then $f$ is in fact holomorphic on all of $A$.

Comment: An hence Cauchy's Theorem would hold?

But, what about $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}=2\pi i$?
$f$ is continuous and holomorphic on all the disk except for $z=0$, which is only one point. Nevertheless, Cauchy's Theorem doesn't hold.

Comment: I dropped a comma, and even with that it would not have been optimally formulated. Should have been "If $f$ is continuous on all of $A$, and holomorphic on $A\setminus D$ ..." . $\frac1z$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Thank you :)

Comment: However, for a clean proof of Cauchy's integral theorem, one way is to prove the theorem for the special case of triangles under the assumption that $f$ is continuous on the entire triangle, and holomorphic except possibly in finitely many points. Then later Riemann's removable singularity theorem shows that the possibly exceptional points weren't actually exceptional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Riemann's removable singularity theorem shows, a function $f$ that is continuous on a region $A$ and holomorphic on $A\setminus D$, where $D$ is a discrete closed subset of $A$ (e.g. finite), is actually holomorphic on all of $A$, so the notion of a continuous function that is holomorphic "except in finitely many points" is only seemingly more general than the notion of holomorphic function. Thus Cauchy's integral theorem and integral formula hold for such functions.

However, the seemingly more general notion is used in at least some proofs of the integral formula, where it is proved for the special case of triangles (or rectangles), which suffices to establish the existence of local primitives and thereby to prove the integral theorem for convex domains (and from that, the general case is derived).